# Using Template Specialization To Discriminate Between Values And Arrays (of Values)

Tags: c++

I am trying to construct a device which will do one thing for a value (specifically, a native type) and another thing for a C-style array of primitives.

This is what I have now, which does not do what I wish.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<class V> void dump_buf(const V& val)
{
    cout << "val = " << val << "\n";
}

template<class A> void dump_buf(const A ary[])
{
    cout << "ary size = " << sizeof(ary) << "\n";
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ary); ++i )
        cout << "\t" << i+1 << " : " << ary[i] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\n";
    int i = 42;
    float f = 3.14f;
    unsigned fib[] = {0,1,1,2,3,5};
    char s[] = "hello";
    dump_buf(i);
    dump_buf(f);
    dump_buf(s);
    dump_buf(fib);
}
```

This doesn't work because `ary` is of type pointer-to-something, not array-of-something.  The output for the above (Intel, x64 compile, VS9) is:

```
val = 42
val = 3.14
ary size = 8
        1 : h
        2 : e
        3 : l
        4 : l
        5 : o
        6 :
        7 : ╠
        8 : ╠
ary size = 8
        1 : 0
        2 : 1
        3 : 1
        4 : 2
        5 : 3
        6 : 5
        7 : 3435973836
        8 : 3435973836
```

But I want the output to be:

```
val = 42
val = 3.14
ary size = 6
        1 : h
        2 : e
        3 : l
        4 : l
        5 : o
        6 :
ary size = 6
        1 : 0
        2 : 1
        3 : 1
        4 : 2
        5 : 3
        6 : 5
```

Note that the desired output for the string is 6 characters rather than 5 because of the null-terminator, which is part of the array.

Is there any way to get this to work, using only Standard C++ and no additional libraries?

Nearly any Standard-conformant technique would be acceptable.  Overloading, template specialization, overriding, class templates...  all are OK.  I'm wide open to almost any technique that will accomplish my goal.

Comment: Instead of a c-style array, you can use std::valarray (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/valarray/) or std::vector (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Comment: @yasouser:  The incoming data type is a C-style array.  This is not variant.

Comment: @John-Dibling: In that case you can convert the array to either a std::valarray or std::vector. If you want to use vector, then you do: `std::vector<int> v(fib, fib + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int))`. If you want to use std::valarray, then: `std::valarray<int> arr(fib, sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int))`.

Comment: @yasouser: or you could write a function that takes a reference to an array, and not do any unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
template<class A, size_t S> void dump_buf(const A (& ary)[S])
{
    cout << "ary size = " << S << "\n";
    for( size_t i = 0; i < S; ++i )
        cout << "\t" << i+1 << " : " << ary[i] << "\n";
}
```

By taking a reference to an array, rather than a pointer to the start of an array, the size is known and available as an inferred template argument.

Also, remember that `sizeof` gives the size in bytes, so when you do want the number of objects in an array (and can't or don't want to use a template like this), you want `sizeof(ary)/sizeof(*ary)`. In both cases, you need a real array, not a pointer to an array, which has lost all knowledge of the array's size.